II want to reorder the bars, but don't know how
I'm using the following code:
library(ggplot2)

g1 = ggplot(data = DadosDVMO)

g1 + geom_bar(aes(y = `ETNIA(IBGE)`, color = `ETNIA(IBGE)`,
                  fill = `ETNIA(IBGE)`)) + xlab('Candidatos a DVMO') + 
  ylab('Grupo Étnico (IBGE)') + ## LABELS NO GRÁFICO
  scale_x_continuous(expand = expansion (add = c(0,200)))


I'm having difficulties with reordering the bars from the bigger to smaller.
Anyone to help?
I tried using "reorder" inside "geom_bar" without sucess.

You can reorder variables by creating a factor. A factor is a data type that represents a categories that can be ordered.
With the {forcats} package, you can use the fct_infreq function to automatically order your variable from bigger to smaller.
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)

# example data
data <- tibble("value" = c(rep("A", 4), rep("B", 2), rep("C", 6)))

data |> 
    mutate(value = fct_infreq(value)) |>
    ggplot(aes(value)) +
    geom_bar()


